# Is getrusage not working for me? Why?

Tags: c++, linux, getrusage

I'm trying to measure the maximum resident set size and I found that you can do so with getrusage:

- https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrusage.html

When I run this

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <sys/resource.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int who = RUSAGE_SELF;
    struct rusage usage;
    int ret = -1;

    vector<int> v(1024);

    ret = getrusage(who, &usage);
    if (ret == 0) cout << usage.ru_maxrss << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the same value as I do when I comment the declaration of the vector.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your compiler maybe optimising out the vector because it isn't being used? Try iterating the vector and pushing values into v.

Comment: I understand that this allows you to get the resource usage up to a certain point, so in theory I could use the vector after that and this should take the vector into account. But yes, I tried writing values on the vector.
Thanks for your comment anyways.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the 1024 to a larger value (e.g. 100,000)? perhaps 1024 is not enough to incur memory increase.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be enough? In theory it's the number of KB, so a vector of 1024 ints should add 4KB. Anyways, I tried with 1024000 and the increase in the output didn't make any sense to me :/
Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code a bit to make sense for you for the data which is shown by the ru_maxrss element of rusage structure.

Here is my code

```
#include <vector>
#include <sys/resource.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int who = RUSAGE_SELF;
    struct rusage usage;
    int ret = -1;
    long int a,b;

getrusage(who, &usage);
a=usage.ru_maxrss;

cout << "Maximum resident set size before vector allocation   "<<a << endl;
    vector<int> v(10240000);

cout<<"Size of vector v in kilobytes (kB)  "<<(v.size()*sizeof(int))/(1024)<<endl;

    ret = getrusage(who, &usage);

    cout<<"Size of integer data type   "<<sizeof(int)<<endl;
    b=usage.ru_maxrss;

    if (ret == 0) 
cout << "Maximum resident set size after vector allocation  "<<b << endl;
 cout<<"Difference between resident set size before and after vector allocation  "<<b-a<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Each time **getrusage()** is called it allocates a different resident set size which is a few kB(approx 600-800) greater than the size allocated for the vector.

Some of the outputs of the above code are as follow 
[image]


[image]

If I reduce the no. of elements in the vector to 1024000 the output is as follow
[image]